# Facebook PHP API problems logging in

Tags: php, facebook

I have came across similar threads on this issue but am yet to find a solution. I have broken down my code into its simplest form but am still struggling to get a user to login.
After login/accepting permissions, the redirect_uri is not redirecting correctly (returning with a 'state' message in the url bar).

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');
require_once('AppInfo.php');


$config = array(
    'appId' => '#####',
    'secret' => '########',
    'cookie' => false
);
$fb = new Facebook($config);

$user = $fb->getUser();
?>
<html> 
 <head> 
  <title>Hello Facebook</title> 
 </head> 
 <body>
<?php
if (!$user) { 
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'read_stream',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000/'
        );

        echo '<a href="'. $fb->getLoginUrl($params).'">Login</a>'; 
}
else { 
?>

<p> Hello World! </p>
<?php echo 'hello world!';
        echo 'value of user: '. $user;
        $params = array( 'next' => 'http://localhost:8000'
                        );
        echo '<a href="'.$fb->getLogoutUrl().'">Logout</a>'; 
?>
 </body> 
</html>
```

The settings within developer for site url are the same (http://localhost:8000/).
Sandbox mode is disabled.
AppId and AppSecret are definitely correct.
Have tried in chrome, firefox, IE with several FB accs.
$user never appears to become true.

Comment: What happens when you click your `Login` link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the most recent version of the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)? There are several versions out there to use, many of which are v2. Make sure you have a v3 download in your project.

To make sure your app is correctly configured on Facebook, test it using this [example.php](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) from the Facebook gitHub.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I ran the example script which pointed me to the real problem. The problem was with the curl command, solution was to add $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false; in base_facebook.php around line 935, before curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);